# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'idris'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I mistakenly deleted the root user in admin which was the only user in the database and now I can no longer connect to my database.

When I try `mysql -u root` I get this error message: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'idris' @ 'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Need help...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070501/regaining-access-to-lost-mysql-password-for-phpmyadmin-on-wamp/29073563#29073563

Comment: the solution you offer me works under windows but i am under linux

Comment: Look at the Duplicates One of those is Linux based