# Change password of MySQL

Tags: mysql, root, change-password, forgot-password, reset-password

I've a problem. I forgot MySQL root password. Then I did all commands  according to the instructions. But my command line returned null?. Why It did not work? . Please help me to solve that problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DinRW.png)

Comment: Never made that method work in windows. Try this instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/29073563/2310830 Its for use with WAMPServer but the process is fairly obvious and usable anywhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly ??? This is documented method. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: *But my command line returned null?. Why It did not work?* Never stop at the middle. *You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the new password. Stop the MySQL server and restart it normally. If you run the server as a service, start it from the Windows Services window. If you start the server manually, use whatever command you normally use.*

Comment: Well how about that. First time I ever got that to work @Akina