# MySQL: PHP: Cannot obtain data from table because of warnings

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to obtain data from table users in MySQL database. Using the code below I am able to log in into the database (doesn't return an error) but it shows warnings when I am trying to read the data from the table (in this case I just select the row to check whether the code works). The code is as follows:

```
<?php

$host_name  = "localhost";
$database   = "aj_database";
$user_name  = "aj_user";
$password   = "password";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "The connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];

$query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin'");
$insert = mysql_query ($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    echo "NO";
} else {
    echo "YES!!!!!!!!";
}

?>
```

With the code above I get the following result:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/adamjudk/public_html/airlinesimulator/login.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/adamjudk/public_html/airlinesimulator/login.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/adamjudk/public_html/airlinesimulator/login.php on line 20

and the result returned is after these errors is

> NO

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error due to incorrect password or some like that

Comment: You mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`

Comment: first try to login phpmyadmin it's work fine. if not then let me know I give you solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' for phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482371/fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-for-phpmyadmin)

Comment: @AdamJ please also vote up my answer. If you found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mysql_query()` instead of `mysqli_query()`

and using `if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)` instead of `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0)`.

Try the quickly updated code.

```
$host_name  = "localhost";
$database   = "aj_database";
$user_name  = "aj_user";
$password   = "password";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "The connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo "NO";
}
else
{
    echo "YES!!!!!!!!";
}
```

Comment: This will still result in NO as mysql_num_rows($query) is simply wrong

Comment: @GerdK I already have changed to `if(mysqli_num_rows($query)` but now also mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @GerdK opps sorry got it.