# Get back the access to the database on local server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've done a mistake and would be really thankful to get help.

I've been using MAMP to create a wordpress website on my computer. Today I've been trying to move in to the actual hosting and I guess I've somehow damaged the database.

The thing is that the default username and password are "root" and i wanted to change that before downloading database from the local server. I did, and after that i couldn't use phpMyAdmin, it suggested me to check config.inc.php. I went to this file and there in the code there were still default "root" username and password.

I changed them to the new ones (the same i used before) and it helped, but only to a certain extention. Now i can use phpMyAdmin, but don't have the rights neither to create a new database, nor to make any changes to the user privileges.

So the question is: how to make it all working as it was working before? :)) Thanks a lot in advance!

The second little question is:

Are there any possibilities to upload and use this messy database to the actual server? Otherwise none of the settings on my website is working and i kinda have to restart making it.

Comment: Look into the Duplicator plugin.

Comment: I don't know if you have seen this or whether it will help but you could have a read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482371/fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-for-phpmyadmin?rq=1

Comment: rnevius, can you pleas tell me what is the duplicator plugin, where can i find it and what should i search inside?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't do much from within phpMyAdmin, it sounds like you may be logged in as the anonymous user, which happens if you try to log in and don't match an existing username/host. Double-check that the username and host you're logging in as are the ones configured in MySQL. You may need to reset your account. Even though the error message is different (due to the use of the anonymous user), this may be helpful: [Fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' for phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482371/fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-for-phpmyadmin)

If your auth_type is 'cookie' or 'http' then you don't need to edit `config.inc.php` with your new login information (since `config.inc.php` shouldn't have it in at all, the user and password fields are only used with auth_type 'config'), only enter it when prompted at login.