# phpmyadmin denied permission on everything (Arch Linux setup)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux, phpmyadmin

I have setup phpmyadmin to be working but if I try and create a new db, edit an existing db or whatever I get

## 1142 (whateverItriedtodo) denied to user pma@localhost.

What is this? I even ran this to grant me permissions (replacing the pass with my own)

```
GRANT USAGE ON mysql.* TO 'pma'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapass';
GRANT SELECT (
    Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,
    Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv,
    File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv,
    Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv,
    Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv
    ) ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv)
    ON mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482371/fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-for-phpmyadmin#26678520

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation but my problem got solved using a different browser. Then from that browser I gave myself rights and now either browser works.