# Can't Access MySQL -- Php ADMIN

Tags: php, mysql

Error:
[image: ERROR]

I've tried the solutions in the other question yet I can't seem to make it work, the error is still stuck and i cant access localhost/phpmyadmin, can someone please help me.

[Fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' for phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482371/fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-for-phpmyadmin)

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ' ';

/ **************/
```

Locate config.inc.php file under C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin and open it in any editor.

Find the following line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '  ';
```

Enter the chosen password inside the quotes. Also, in order to make
    localhost/phpmyadmin ask for a username and password, find the following line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Change the above line to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

and so forth.

Comment: Are you tried: user root, password root or user root, password blank?. That error is because you are providing wrong username or wrong password. EDITED. You change question, now you are getting a problem on config file. You must revert your config.inc.php. Best is edit config file throw phpmyadmin putting config.inc.php into /config dir and run script http://yourserver/yourPhpMyAdminRoute/setup

Comment: @hokusai I've tried the first option you gave me regarding the user root, password root, etc.. I've managed to have one working, but then after logging in, all my databases are gone ...

Comment: @hokusai

As for the second part whereas you mentioned about /config dir and run script, can't seem to understand it .

Comment: Sorry, I mean this: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-setup-script